# Google script string with variable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a column of names that I am looping through and creating a new sheet from the value in each row.
I'm then trying to insert a string into cell A1 on each sheet. The string has a pointer in it to A1, A2, A3 etc
My code  creates a new sheet and on the new sheet inserts a string into A1. The first sheet is fine - points to A1 , the second points  to A11, the 3rd to A21 etc
Ideally I just want to put a variable in my cell range but can't see how to do that anywhere. If I just use I, then it starts at 0 so I'm out by one.
Probably just being stupid but new to this. I can do it in VB but can't see what the problem is with this.

```
var sheetName = dataRange.getValues();

for (i in sheetName) {
    var row = sheetName[i];

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.insertSheet(row,i+1,{});
    var c1='=GOOGLEFINANCE(Parameters!$A$';
    var c2= i+1;
    var c3=', "all", Parameters!$B$2,Parameters!$B$4, "DAILY")';
    var c4 = c1.concat(c2);
    var c5 = c4.concat(c3);

    ss.getRange("A1").setValue(c5);
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);
}
```

Comment: Please checkout [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for .. in` loops in javascript make the iterator a string even though it's a number.
Your script first concatenates `"0"` and `1`, this coerces `1` to a string and creates `"01"`.
`A01` then finally becomes `A1` due to spreadsheet logic.

Then `i` is `1` and concatenates `"1" + 1` which creates `"11"` and so on.

Try `var c2= parseInt(i) + 1;` instead.

Comment: that sounds rather silly! Why convert to string? .... cheers will try this later when I get a chance

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks very much.